# Servlets with overlapping pattern

Tags: java, servlets

I need to implement 3 servlets, with pattern overlapping.

**The first** servlet would handle for example:

```
/context/categories
```

with a pattern like this:

```
@WebServlet("/categories"))
```

**The second** servlet would handle for example:

```
/context/categories/category1/
```

with a pattern like this:

```
@WebServlet("/categories/*")
```

**And the third** would be like:

```
/context/categories/category1/category1contentname
```

But i cant give the proper pattern to the third, because the second servlet will catch the call, or neither will.
My question is, how can i give the correct patterns to the servlets, especially the second and the third?
I know the /* suffix, and the *. prefix, but it doesnt seem to work properly so far.

Comment: Try to use web.xml declaration instead of annotations because you can define order of servlets mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that with

```
/context/categories/category1/
```

you mean that the `/category1` path segment can have any value.

Basically, you can't with Servlet `url-pattern` elements. The [Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) says the following about path matching:

> The path used for mapping to a servlet is the request URL from the
>   request object  minus the context path and the path parameters. The
>   URL path mapping rules  below are used in order. The first successful
>   match is used with no further matches  attempted:
>
> 1. The container will try to find an exact match of the path of the request to the path  of the servlet. A successful match selects the
>      servlet.
> 2. The container will recursively try to match the longest path-prefix. This is done by stepping down the path tree a directory at a time, using the ’/’ character as a  path separator. The longest
>      match determines the servlet selected.
> 3. [...]
> 4. [...]

The mapping

```
@WebServlet("/categories/*")
```

will match everything that starts with `/categories`.

As I see it, you don't have many solutions. Declare a single `Servlet` with the pattern `/categories/*` and internally do some dispatching. You should look into the [Front Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).

Comment: Thank you!

After several hours, i've come to the same answer as you wrote, that i cant get it working that way, so i just changed the servlets paths to different ones.
But thanks for the conformation!:)